# Developing a music live stream site using reactjs and drf

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-hooks

when a song (div) is clicked on and currently playing, i add a "play" to the class list. when the user clicks on another song i want to remove that play from the initial div (song) that was clicked on and add it to the current div that was click ASAP. Also when the song is been played i'm having a delay in response, like i'd have to click twice first click will fetch the song then the second click will then play it. how can i rectify it so when i click once everything fetches and plays asap. i have used the fetch function and applied a call back yet still having same issues.

```
 const audio=document.querySelector('#audio')
const music_container=document.querySelector('#music_container')

const [image, setImage]=useState('')
const [posts, setPosts]=useState([])
const [icon,setIcon]=useState(faPlay)
const[playing,setPlaying]=useState(false)
const[music,setMusic]=useState('')
const[audioUrl,setAudioUrl]=useState('')

// const progress=useRef()
const[progress,SetCurrentProgress]=useState(0)





    function getAllPosts(){
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            // console.log(data)
            setPosts(data)
        })
        
    }
    // console.log(posts.artist_name)

// LOAD ALL POSTS
        // function soundrimage(){
        //     // setImage(music_img)
            
        // }

        useEffect(()=>{
            getAllPosts() 
            // console.log(this)
        },[])
    


// LOAD AND CONTROL MUSIC
            function playSong(e){
                // music_audio=music.`http://127.0.0.1:8000${audio}`
                
                    
                e.target.classList.add('play')
                setIcon(faPause)
                setPlaying(true)
                audio.play()
            
            
               
                
                
            }

            function pauseSong(e){
               

                
                e.target.classList.remove('play')
                setIcon(faPlay)
                setPlaying(true)
                console.log(music.audio)
                audio.pause()
            
               
            }

        function playPause(e){
            
            
            let isplaying=e.target.classList.contains('play') 
            
            
            

               
                if(isplaying){
                    pauseSong(e)
                }else{
                    playSong(e)
                }


                
            
        }


        const UpdateProgress=(e)=>{
            // console.log(e.target.duration)
            const {duration,currentTime}=e.target

            const ProgressPercent=(currentTime/duration)*100
            
            SetCurrentProgress(`${ProgressPercent}`)
            

        }


    const setAudioSrc=(e)=>{
        // setAudioUrl(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/${e.target.id}/`)
        
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/${e.target.id}/`).then(
            response=>response.json()
            ).then(data=>{
            // console.log(data)
            setMusic(data)
            
            // if(e.target === e.currentTarget){
            e.target.nextSibling.id='audio'
                
            // }else{
            //     e.target.nextSibling.id=' '
            // }
            
            playPause(e)
            })
            
        // console.log(e.target.nextSibling.id)
        
        
        
    }
        // console.log(progress.current)

    
        const setProgress=(e)=>{
            const width=e.target.clientWidth
            // console.log(e)
            const clickX=e.nativeEvent.offsetX
            // console.log(clickX)
            const duration=audio.duration
            // console.log(duration)

            audio.currentTime=(clickX/width)*duration

        }

    
  


 


    // MUSIC INFO
    // const music_image= document.querySelector("#music_image")



    
   
    
   


return(
    <body>
         
        
        <Navbar/>
        <main className="landing">






    {posts.map((post,i)=>(

        <div className="music_holder" key={i}>

       
                <div className="music_container" >
                  
                                
                    <img  className="music_image" 
                    
                    // onMouseEnter={e=>setAudioSrc(e)}  
                    // onMouseLeave={()=>{
                    //     setAudioUrl('')
                    // }}
                    onClick={(e)=>{playPause(e)}} 
                    src={'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+post.image} />

                   


                    {/* <button >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} onClick={(e)=>{playPause(e)}}   id="playBtn"  />
                    </button> */}



                    <div className="music_overlay"  
                    id={post.id}  

                    // onMouseEnter={e=>setAudioSrc(e)}  
                    // onMouseLeave={(e)=>{
                    //     // setAudioUrl('')
                    //     e.target.nextSibling.id=' '
                    // }}
                    onClick={e=>setAudioSrc(e)}
                    ></div>

                    
                    <audio src={music.audio} id="" onTimeUpdate={e=>UpdateProgress(e)}/>


                    </div>

                <div className="caption_holder">
                    <p className="caption">{post.title}</p>
                </div>
                   
            
                    
            
            </div>
                
                
                )
        
            )}
```